# Using a regular expression in C# to match rtf-formatted text

Tags: c#, regex, rtf

I need to use a regexp to extract bold text from rtf formatted text. For example: The \b brown fox\b0 jumped over the  \b lazy dog\b0.

How can I get only the text enclosed between \b and \b0?  I tried this expression but it returned only the first match: `(\\b.+\b0[^\\b])`

Comment: Escape the backslashes, `\\ `. Also make the matching non-greedy, `+?`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = @"The \b brown fox\b0 jumped over the \b lazy dog\b0";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\\b(.*?)\\b0");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(s))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Alternatively you can use captures:

```
string s = @"The \b brown fox\b0 jumped over the \b lazy dog\b0";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(.*?\\b(.*?)\\b0)*");
foreach (Capture c in rgx.Match(s).Groups[2].Captures)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression:

```
\\b([\s\S]+?)\\b0
```